# Mysql info in select tag

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I've been trying to figure out how to do this but I've had no luck.

I have a database that includes ID, name, date, and username

I have a simple submit form that generates an id and a user adds a name and an event date then it logs the username, However I would like to take that date and then have it appear in a select tag with the format of Name - Date and have it sorted by the closest date. I want to view info about that event when someone clicks it. But I can't figure out how to make it appear in the select tag. I don't even know where to start with this. all help appreciated.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$id = uniqid(rand(), false);
$name=$_POST['name'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$username = $_POST['username'];


// Insert data into database

$sql="INSERT INTO events (id, name, date, username)
VALUES
('$id', '$name', '$date', '$username')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

error_log(implode("-",$_POST));



$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Your question is missing some crucial information: What is it you try to accomplish, and why? Describing this is probably a good point to start.

Comment: See about prepared and bound queries

Comment: @KIKOSoftware "I would like to take that date and then have it appear in a select tag with the format of Name - Date and have it sorted by the closest date. I want to view info about that event when someone clicks it. But I can't figure out how to make it appear in the select tag. I don't even know where to start with this. all help appreciated." ???

Comment: @DannyFanta: "What is it you try to accomplish, and why?"